# How to work with libraries that don't support unicode characters

Tags: c#

In my case, I recently picked up the [irrKlang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/) library which allows me to work with audio files without doing too much work. Then I ran into the issue where unicode characters in filepaths were not supported by the library. It either reads it incorrectly (I would've thought even if it was read wrong, it could still find the file), or simply ignores it, leaving me with invalid file paths.

Searched their support forums for a solution to this, but all I got out of it was "unicode? uhhh why not just use ascii?" kind of attitude towards unicode, which I suppose is not uncommon.

What are some techniques that I could use to reliably pass unicode strings to  libraries that don't have unicode support?

Comment: The only strategy you need for libraries with no Unicode support is the ability to run *as fast as you can* away from them. There's just no excuse for that kind of colossal stupidity in the 21st century. And you can't afford to inflict that kind of colossal stupidity on *your* users. They will neither care nor understand when you try to explain that the serious limitations of your app are actually the fault of a third-party library that you utilize and have no control over. They'll just see a seriously limited, broken app that you won't fix.

Comment: @CodyGray Just because you don't know how to manipulate a program using non unicode strings, does not mean they are useless.  For example those programs that only deal with ASCII strings will not suffer from endianness issues.

Second I do agree with respect to what is presented to the end user, however that does not mean the programmer should be incapable of compromise.

Third, much code in existance was written a while ago and has been bridged by resolving to adresses(which any library knows how to interpret) using a unicode api, and passing the resulting reference to the required API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put you don't, you can pass through them using a byte array, and then interpret it back as a unicode array on the other end, but if it doesn't do unicode, it doesn't do unicode.

There is no point in passing a unicode string to a library that is incapable of interpreting it.

If you need to do something specific(like using a load command on a filesystem with unicode paths e.g HFS+), then don't.  Rather use the system provided file APIs and push the data into the uncooperative libraries constructor.

If you're seriously having problems with this unicode file path business, cause you don't work well with passing addresses and bitstreams around, then a simple solution is to make your own function:

```
obj_ptr* loadObjFromUnicodePath(path)
{
//create tmp ASCII named symlink to file at arg(path).
//call load API of irrKlang on symlink.
//delete tmp symlink, return object.
}
```

Comment: That's all fine and good, except when the path actually contains characters that don't convert nicely into ASCII. That's not just a theoretical problem, I have lots of paths on my machine right now that contain Unicode characters that have no equivalent ASCII representation. If the lib can't handle that, it's going to choke and be unable to work with the file.

Comment: @CodyGray The trick is to *create* an ASCII symlink to the file, not convert the Unicode path to ASCII. That being said, your comment under the question should probably be an answer.